# Adjoining torsion points from abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ be the field generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by all of the (projective) coordinates of all of the torsion points of all abelian varieties defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is $L$ algebraically closed?

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since I realized that the argument does not work (subgroups may have different composition factors than the group they are contained in). Still, I have the feeling that the answer is no.

Comment: My feeling was apparently wrong -- nice and short answer!

Comment: @MichaelStoll  Still, why have you considered GSp and not GL?

Comment: Because of the Weil pairing: there is a Galois-equivariant alternating pairing $A[n] \times A[n] \to \mu_n$, so the image of Galois in $\operatorname{GL}(2d,{\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z})$ is contained in $\operatorname{GSp}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $\lambda\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the elliptic curve 
$$
E_\lambda\colon y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)
$$
has $(\lambda,0)$ as $2$-torsion point and is defined over (a subfield of) $L=\mathbb{Q}(\lambda)$. Its Weil restriction $A_\lambda:=\operatorname{Res}_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(E_\lambda)$ is an abelian variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and shares the same points of $E_\lambda$, including their torsion structure, so $\lambda\in \mathbb{Q}(A_\lambda[2])$.

**EDIT** As Urlich observed, what I wrote was wrong/useless: indeed, the defining property of Weil restricition is that the $\mathbb{Q}$-points of $\operatorname{Res}_{L/\mathbb{Q}}$ coincide with the $L$-ones of $E_\lambda$, so the point corresponding to $(\lambda,0)$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Instead of $\operatorname{Res}_{L/\mathbb{Q}}$, (assume $L/\mathbb{Q}$ Galois, which makes no harm, and) consider $A_\lambda=\prod_{\sigma\in G(L/\mathbb{Q})}E^\sigma$, which is an abelian variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has the required property: the point
$$
\big((\lambda,0),O,O,\dots,O\big)
$$
where $O$ is the unit has the required property (namely, it generates $L$ and is torsion): thanks to Felipe for the solution.

Comment: The point $(\lambda, 0)$ is an $L$-rational point of $E_{\lambda}$ so corresponds to a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point of $A_{\lambda}$.

Comment: The dimension of the resulting abelian variety $A_\lambda$ is unbounded when one ranges over $\lambda$, right?

Comment: Ulrich is correct, but Filippo is almost correct. Instead of restriction of scalars use the product of the conjugates.

Comment: What if the abelian varieties are restricted to be simple? (By the way, regarding the question that @Pablo is hinting at: the answer is negative if those are required to have bounded degree. This is just because the Galois group of the $n$-level torsion of a $d$-dimensional abelian variety is constrained by $\mathrm{GL}(2d,\mathbb{Z}/n)$.)

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Is there anything special that we know about the Galois representations attached to simple abelian varieties? Maybe something about their images could be of help...

Comment: @Pablo: I am clueless as to whether we should expect a negative answer in that case...

Comment: @Felipe: I am lost here. I always thought the product of the conjugates *was* the Weil restriction.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Not in general. They are twists of each other. Maybe, in Filippo's case, it doesn't matter as he is base-changing to $L$ but then he needs to use a different point, since Ulrich is definitely correct and that point corresponds to a rational point on the Weil restriction.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I guess part of the problem is that the $\mathbb{Q}$-structure of the product of the conjugates is ambiguous. It's only after fixing this structure that one can talk about the field of definition of an algebraic point. In the case of a variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, the structure over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the restriction of scalars is not that of the $n$-th power of the original variety.

Comment: @Felipe: But I cannot think of *two* natural Galois actions making this product "defined over $\mathbb{Q}$", unless of course the original $E_\lambda$ is.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I guess you are right, unless the curve is defined over a subfield (not necessarily $\mathbb{Q}$). Still, one needs to be careful about the point that is picked. In the restriction of scalars, $(\lambda,0)$ corresponds to $\prod (\lambda^{\sigma},0) \in \prod E^{\sigma}$ which is rational. It is the point $((\lambda,0),{\cal{O}},\ldots)\in \prod E^{\sigma}$ that generates $L$.

Answer (score 13):

Another proof that $L = \,\overline{\bf \!Q\!}\,$:
Clearly $L$ is contained in $\,\overline{\bf \!Q\!}\,$,
so we need only show $L$ contains every algebraic number $x \notin \bf Q$.
Let $P(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $x$.  If $\deg P$ is odd,
then the class of $((x,0)) - (\infty)$ is a $2$-torsion point on
the Jacobian of the elliptic or hyperelliptic curve $y^2 = P(x)$.
If $\deg P$ is even, then the class of $((x,0)) - (\infty)$ is 
a $2$-torsion point on the Jacobian of the
elliptic or hyperelliptic curve $y^2 = x P(x)$.
**QED**

Comment: Excellent. Now, to answer the further question, can you modify this so that the associated Jacobians are geometrically simple? Most of the ones you construct will be, but not all, I think. Maybe use $y^2=P(x)Q(x)$ for a generic $Q(x)$ so that $\deg(PQ)$ is odd?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, multiplying $P(x)$ by some auxiliary polynomial
with degree of the appropriate parity must work, though proving it
might be beyond the scope of a reasonable MO answer, unless some
helpful result is already known (like a strong enough
upper bound on the proportion of Jacobians of hyperlliptic genus-$g$ curves
of height $\leq H$ that are not geometrically simple).

Comment: The following paper might help: MR1361754 
Masser, D. W.(CH-BASL); Wüstholz, G.(CH-ETHZ)
Factorization estimates for abelian varieties.
Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math. No. 81 (1995), 5–24. They give effective estimates for the degree of the isogeny and fields of definition for the factorization of $A$ into simple factors. So one might be able to use that to prove that almost all of the Jacobians of $y^2=PQ$, counted by height, are simple. It wouldn't follow directly, but might be the right tool to apply. (Just a thought.)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies this is a very nice and explicit construction. Following Silverman, and Dimitrov I would like to know if you can think of some natural "big" family of abelian varieties (with unbounded ranks) such that adding all their torsion points to the rationals will not result in an algebraically closed field? That is, something like the simple varieties...